# Symfony v2.2.1 kernel.trust_proxy_headers must be defined

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php, symfony-2.2

Trying to use Symfony v2.2.1.

I can clear the dev cache without any problem, but when I try to clear prod cache, it keeps telling me:

[Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\InvalidArgumentException]
  The parameter "kernel.trust_proxy_headers" must be defined.

I've done:

- removing everything inside app/cache/*.
- put trust_proxy_headers: true/false in config.yml, config_prod.yml and even parameters.yml.

Is there anything I can do to fix this?

My composer.json is here http://pastebin.com/ux8qxDdb .

Is there anything I'm missing?
How can I fix this?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried the top google hits? https://github.com/symfony/symfony-standard/issues/170
http://forum.symfony-project.org/viewtopic.php?f=23&t=36795

Comment: Yes, all those "fixes" did not work for me.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask "Have you thoroughly searched for an answer before asking your question? Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you found and why it didn’t meet your needs."
From the information you've given your problem appears to be identical to those problems linked - can you say how it is different, so people can help you?

Comment: I took a look at your composer.json file.  You have a lot of dependencies in there.  Hard to isolate.  Have you considered just moving to S2.3?  The parameter goes away there.  S2.2 is a throw away release.  No real point in upgrading to it.

Comment: Yeah, i'm just going to 2.3.